# Conflicting constraints 'value' and 'System.Enum' when using explicit interface implementation

Tags: c#, c#-7.3

I'm building an extensible system for converting between various enum types. The idea is that a developer can inherit a BaseEnumConverter class and provide an implementation for an abstract method `Convert<TDestinationEnumType>` .

This Convert method will then be called by an internal system. The requirement is that any implementation of this method will automatically be called directly after some validation logic.

I enforced this rule by using an interface, a private method and an explicit interface implementation:

```cs
public interface IEnumConverter
{
    TDestinationEnumType? Convert<TDestinationEnumType>(Enum sourceEnumValue) where TDestinationEnumType : struct, Enum;
}

public abstract class BaseEnumConverter : IEnumConverter
{
    public abstract TDestinationEnumType? Convert<TDestinationEnumType>(Enum sourceEnumValue)
        where TDestinationEnumType : struct, Enum;

    private TDestinationEnumType? ConvertWithValidation<TDestinationEnumType>(Enum sourceEnumValue)
        where TDestinationEnumType : struct, Enum
    {
        if (sourceEnumValue.GetType() == typeof(TDestinationEnumType))
        {
            return (TDestinationEnumType)sourceEnumValue;
        }
        return Convert<TDestinationEnumType>(sourceEnumValue);
    }

    TDestinationEnumType? IEnumConverter.Convert<TDestinationEnumType>(Enum sourceEnumValue)
    {
        return ConvertWithValidation<TDestinationEnumType>(sourceEnumValue);
    }
}
```

This way, any calls to an IEnumConverter reference will automatically run the validation logic, then the conversion logic.

**The problem**

The signature for the explicit interface definition has the following compilation error:

`Type parameter 'TDestinationEnumType' inherits conflicting constraints 'value' and 'System.Enum'`

Removing the 'struct' constraint does remove the compilation error, however it then prevents me from returning a null result from the Convert method, which is also a requirement for this system.

So what I'd like to know is:

- What exactly is causing this error?
- Are there any workarounds? Not returning null is not an option for me.

Comment: How about returning a boolean to indicate success/failure, and passing the Enum as an 'out' parameter? (similar to the .NET int.TryParse method) It would not be able to set it to NULL exactly, but may give the flexibility required.

Comment: I don't get any compilation error with your code.

Comment: On further investigation, this appears to be an issue with ReSharper. Sorry for wasting your time. And @Wiz, thanks very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further investigation, this appears to be an issue with ReSharper.